# Are Hard Drive Motors Stepper Motors?

Tags: stepper-motor, hardware, hard-drive

Can a hard drive motor been controlled by a stepper motor? Like the one shown below? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Some very old hard drives (early 1980s, 10MB) used stepper motors for the head movement, but never for the spindle motor. So, ... no.

Comment: There's no stepper motor in your picture? So what are you asking?

Comment: @user_1818839 Any idea what those drive models were? I remember my Uncle's PC/XT hard drive making the sound of a stepper motor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are actually asking

> Can I control a hard drive spindle motor with a stepper motor driver?

And I guess that the linked image is of some cheap infrared remote controlled stepper driver thing you found on aliexpress, eBay or dealExtreme?

If that is the case, no. The spindle motor which spins the platters is a three phase [brushless DC motor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor), while the stepper driver is for driving two phase [stepper motors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper_motor).

Comment: if that was the question, the question would be per-rules off-topic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller AFAIK, no it's not. What specific rule would it break? *In its current state* it certainly is "unclear what you are asking" and something equivalent might be already posted somewhere, but those wouldn't make the question technically off topic, although they are reasons for closing it.

Comment: if it's some ebay device, that would be purchase advice?

Comment: @MarcusMüller OP isn't asking which X should be bought (a "shopping question"). OP is asking if X is compatible with Y. It's not purchase advice.